# Displays won't sleep while screen-saver is running

Tags: display, sleep-wake, power-management, screensaver

So, I've got my screen-saver set to come on after 5 minutes,

[image: Start after: 5 Minutes]

… and my display to sleep after 1 hour:

[image]

Unfortunately, I get up every morning, and the displays are still running Aerial. I really, really don't want to burn out my expensive 5k monitors by powering them 24/7.

How can I ensure that 1. my computer requires my computer requires my password after a few minutes, 2. my displays *don't* turn off until they've been idle for a few hours (they take forever to boot back up — ~10 seconds before I can log-in when I sit down), and 3. my displays *do* turn off after a sufficient idle-period?

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced similar problems. The easiest and guaranteed working solution which i found out after lots of experimentation is to get this software Better Touch Tool and configure a quick shortcut "Ctrl+L" to lock/sleep the display. So I can manually do it when I am stepping out from the desk or for overnight downloads.

You might already have done this. I am just putting this here for other's sake. You will have to enable this option too so that when u lock the display, it asks for the login password when u wake it up. Hope this helps.

[image]